# Trolley weight savings "question"

Tags: discussion

[This post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65259/can-the-removal-of-a-duty-free-sales-trolley-result-in-a-measurable-reduction-in) asks a very clear question in the title, and then proceeds to perform the rough arithmetic to estimate an answer. The math itself seems fine, and the question seems perfectly appropriate, but I fail to see how they didn't just answer their own question.

What could an answer state that the original question doesn't already state?

Comment: I think the answers to that question answer *your* question.

Answer (score 4):

As I am the poster of the question, I think I should mention some things that otherwise I believe are obvious.

1. The math might sound trivial and correct but it's easy to get them wrong. In my questions I've made **3 mistakes**. One that I've included the engines which is really unnecessary, second that I've made my calculations having the wrong engine type in mind and finally and more gravely, I forgot to multiply by 100 so the 0,012% became 0,00012%. Actually I am ashamed for that last part.
2. What I want to hear and I hope I am not the only one, is real world stories. "War stories". Not theories. Someone might say

   > "hey listen, the wind is so unpredictable, that the 0,05% is nothing, it can be the trolley removal or that you had way too many tail winds. **You can't know**"

That's just an example.

If there is someone that has an insight, why not have a real world answer after all?

Comment: Did the someone who told the iPad story count? :P

Comment: @ymb1 all the "someones" count! But as you can see, I'm not the one who's hard to please! :D

Answer (score 3):

Answers can (and do) clarify if the original asker's assumptions are correct. I see no inherent problem with this.

As an aside, you should see a `close` link below the question where you can register your vote for this question to be put on hold. At the time of writing 3 have already done so for a selection of reasons you may agree with.

Comment: Would the question be better phrased as "How does removing the trolley..."? What bothers me about the current framing is that it boils down to a yes or no question.  However what most people seem to want (based on the votes) is a discussion on how a small weight reduction actually effects the aircraft, not whether or not the phenomenon is really happening. tl;dr everyone agrees that reducing weight will save fuel, so the question should be tweaked.

Comment: @zymhan Perhaps. You also have the ability to suggest an improvement to the title/body of this question and are free to do so.